# Take kernel dump on-demand from user-space without kernel debugging (Windows)

Tags: windbg, dump, windows-kernel, procdump

What would be the simplest and most portable way (in the sense of only having to copy a few files to the target machine, like `procdump` is) to generate a kernel dump that has handle information?

`procdump` has the `-mk` option which generates a limited dump file pertaining to the specified process. It is reported in WinDbg as:
`Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available`. Most of the commands I try (`!handle`, `!process 0 0`) fail to read the data.

Seems that officially, `windbg` and `kd` would generate dumps (which would require kernel debugging).

A weird solution I found is using `livekd` with `-ml`: `Generate live dump using native support (Windows 8.1 and above only).`. `livekd` still looks for `kd.exe`, but does not use it :) so I can trick it with an empty file, and does not require kernel debugging. Any idea how that works?

Comment: That livekd thing is probably a bug: since it will use `kd` usually, it probably checks the presence at startup, even if not needed when using `-ml`.

Comment: As snoone answered it uses undocumented Api [here is a link to some bin andsrc](https://crashdmp.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/livedump-1-0-is-available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveKD uses the undocumented NtSystemDebugControl API to capture the memory dump. While you can easily find information about that API online the easiest thing to do is just use LiveKD.